# Print unsigned char as character (which format specifier?)

Tags: c

I have unsigned char variable which stores ASCII code of some symbol (e.g., '1').
I want to print the symbol. Am I using the correct format specifier? Is this well defined? or should I cast it to int inside `sprintf`?

```
unsigned char unsignedCharVar = 49;
sprintf(dest,"%c", unsignedCharVar); // should print '1'
```

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: But regarding your problem, I sense a bit of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this? Is there a reason you use `unsigned char` to store, essentially, characters? And if you want to print the characters *as a character* then you need to cast the variable to be correct, which might cause UB if `char` is signed and the value is over 127.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, let's assume I need to use unsigned char array to store *character* so how do I print it? Where do I do the cast?

Comment: `sprintf(dest,"%c", unsignedCharVar); // should print '1'` here `sprintf` does not print anything. try `printf("%s",dest);` after your `sprintf`.

Comment: @Jayesh: I know that I am asking about format specifier inside `sprintf`.

Comment: @user300234 then you no need to cast to char.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I know sometimes unsigned char gets promotoed either to int or rarely to unsigned int. That is why I am interested how to do it correctly. (ps. that doc says the argument is converted to unsigned char first?)

Comment: printf's family `%c`  requires an `int` as argument. So cast to `(int)unsignedCharVar`.  Inside the function is converted to `unsigned char` and output. But perhaps cast not required.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY:  though this doc (en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) says "The argument is first converted to unsigned char" strangely

Comment: see [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)  **7.19.6.1 The fprintf function 8**

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: It says: "If no l length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an
unsigned char, and the resulting character is written"-  so it seems (int) cast is not needed inside sprintf?

Comment: it(cast to int) is not done in the interior of the printf.

Comment: also see ditto **6.5.2.2 Function calls 6**

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: In the end it is still not clear - anyway I am avoiding this technique now altogether and using different approach just based on memcpy

Comment: first as fact, `char` type is that they might unsigned or signed. (**6.2.5 Types 15**). But no one has been as `char x;`...`printf("%c", (int)x)//x might unsigned char`.  I think this is because they represent the same value as an `int` even promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`. So cast is not required.

Answer (score 1):

`u` specifies unsigned for all types so try `%uc`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to cast to char, since (non-extended) ASCII has codes 0-127, which means the representation is the same in both unsigned and signed char. You just have to make sure that your unsigned char contains a valid value.

Comment: @user300234 `unsigned char` will be promoted to `unsigned int` only if a `unsigned int` is expected. Where did you read otherwise?

Comment: @user300234 that answer just confirm what I said. "This is because of default argument promotions as printf() is variadic function. This means that unsigned char value is always promoted to int."

Comment: @user300234 Even if you run your code on a machine where 'char' and 'int' is 16bits long, which I doubt that exist, `%c` will always works because your argument value will be never be greater than 127, so UB will never happen.